# Function and algebraic system

Tags: universal-algebra, algebraic-systems

Let $f$ be a surjective function from $X$ to $\{1,2,3\}$. Let $* :X^2 \to X$, such that $$f(x)\neq f(y) \implies f(x) \neq f(xy)\neq f(y), $$ and $$f(x)=f(y)\implies f(x)=f(xy).$$ Let's call the triple $A=(X,f,*)$ a box. It's clear, that the operation $*$ is not associative for any $f$. Moreover, the following property is not satisfied for all $x,y\in X$:
$$x(yy)=(xy)y$$
Similarly, it does not hold that
$$(yy)x=y(yx).$$
Also, there are not $x$ that are absorbing or neutral.
I'm wondering what other properties such a system might have? I think, that $*$ might be a commutative. I don't know if $A$ can have an analogue of invertibility, as in a quasigroup. I'm also interested in the universally algebraic properties of boxes.

Comment: The operation $*$ does not have to satisfy any non-trivial identity. If $\cdot$ is a binary  operation on the set $A$, then define $X=A\times\{1,2,3\}$, where $f:X\rightarrow\{1,2,3\}$ is the projection mapping and where $(x,i)*(y,j)=(x\cdot y,k)$ whenever $|\{i,j,k\}|=3$ and $(x,i)*(y,i)=(x\cdot y,i)$. If $\phi:(X,*)\rightarrow(A,\cdot)$ is the mapping where $\phi((x,i))=x$, then $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism, so $(X,*)$ does not need to satisfy any non-trivial identities.

Comment: Observe that the boxes can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with the multi-sorted algebraic structures $(A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},(*_{i,j})_{i=1,j=1}^{3})$ such that  $*_{i,j}:A_{i,j}\rightarrow A_{k}$ whenever $|\{i,j,k\}|\in\{1,3\}$; the operations $*_{i,j}$ are not required to satisfy any identity whatsoever.

Comment: The smallest (non-empty) box is the box where $f$ is the identity mapping. In this case, $*$ is a binary operation on $\{1,2,3\}$ where $i*j=k$ whenever $|\{i,j,k\}|\in\{1,3\}$. This algebraic structure $(\{1,2,3\},*)$ is an involutive quandle that satisfies the commutativity identity $x*y=y*x$. $(\{1,2,3\},*)$ is also a squag (Steiner quasigroup).

Comment: This correspondence, although obvious, is interesting to me, because, as you noticed, nothing nontrivial is expected from the construction.

Comment: @Joseph Van Name, are there prerequisites for similar properties for large boxes?